# transform: scale offsets element

Tags: html, css

Child with

```
transform: scale(0.544885);
transform-origin: center;
```

Does not get centered in parent

https://codepen.io/rudza/pen/odLwYW

Comment: Well obviously. It's not centered without the scaling, what makes you think it will be centered with the scaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` to `parent`

```
.parent {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50%;
    display: flex; // Added
    align-items: center; // Added
    justify-content: center; // Added
}
```

or another solution is `text-align: center` to the `parent`

```
.parent {
        background-color: red;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center; //Added
    }
```

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :)

Comment: First one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Center the text within the parent.

```
.parent {
  text-align: center; /* <--- here */
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to child :

```
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
```

[Here is your codepen udpated](https://codepen.io/sandwell/pen/odLeRR)

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'display: flex' to the child

```
 .child {
    background-color: green;
   width: 420px;
  height: 478.9887640449438px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0.544885);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.544885);
  transform-origin: center;
  display: flex;}
```